# Some quick questions about Windows API control IDs

Tags: winapi

I've got a few questions here about control IDs:

1. Can they be changed at runtime by setting `GWL(P)_ID`? Or will the dialog manager not be fooled? Since this is a framework, I need to generate them at runtime; initially they are 0.
2. What is the uniqueness scope of control IDs, the whole toplevel window or just the immediate parent of a control? Controls in my framework are stored in a custom container window, there are multiple such in each toplevel window.

Thanks.

Comment: The question doesn't make much sense.  Before you can change the ID, you first have to find the control back with GetDlgItem().  That requires knowing the ID.  No point in changing it.  If it is a "framework" and you create your own dialogs then there's no point in changing the ID, just give it the right one immediately.

Comment: @Hans: Calling `CreateWindow[Ex]` returns a window handle. You don't need to find what you already have readily available.

Comment: Having IDs properly set up is necessary for correct dialog tab navigation. This is the Windows backend of a library to provide a portable GUI, so I need to generate the IDs at runtime.

Comment: I'm a dolt; it's actually the Z-order that determines the tab order... \*bangs head on wall\* I know some things about the Windows API but not others!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1**

Control IDs can be changed by calling [`SetWindowLongPtr`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644898.aspx):

```
SetWindowLongPtr(hwndChild, DWL_ID, new_id);
```

**Question 2**

From the documentation for [`CreateWindow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632679.aspx), with my emphasis:

> hMenu [in, optional]
>
> A handle to a menu, or specifies a child-window identifier depending
>   on the window style. For an overlapped or pop-up window, hMenu
>   identifies the menu to be used with the window; it can be NULL if the
>   class menu is to be used. For a child window, hMenu specifies the
>   child-window identifier, an integer value used by a dialog box control
>   to notify its parent about events. The application determines the
>   child-window identifier; **it must be unique for all child windows with
>   the same parent window**.

Or from the documentation of [`GetDlgItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645481.aspx):

> You can use the GetDlgItem function with any parent-child window pair,
>   not just with dialog boxes. As long as the hDlg parameter specifies a
>   parent window and the child window has a unique identifier (as
>   specified by the hMenu parameter in the CreateWindow or CreateWindowEx
>   function that created the child window), GetDlgItem returns a valid
>   handle to the child window.

So the scope for IDs is the parent window. But this also tells you that you can specify the ID when you create the child window via the re-purposed `hMenu` parameter.

Comment: Yeah; I knew about creating the IDs in `CreateWindowEx()`; I'm dumb for not checking there for the second question =P Thanks for the answer in the meantime; it confirms the first question anyway. (I was mainly wondering if doing that would have any caveats; I guess the answer is no.)